# Multi-threading in SQL Server

Tags: multithreading, sql-server-2008

Lets say I have a table like:

```
a     b    c     d    e      f
---------------------------------
1.2  2.3  4.4   5.1  6.7    11.9   
7.2  2.3  4.3   5.1  4.7    3.9   
1.9  5.3  3.3   5.1  3.7    8.9   
5.2  2.7  7.4   9.1  1.7    2.9
```

If I have to compute something as the sqrt of the multiplication of the sum of the columns

```
SQRT(sum(a*a)),SQRT(sum(a*b)),SQRT(sum(a*c)),SQRT(sum(a*d)),SQRT(sum(a*e)),SQRT(sum(a*f)),SQRT(sum(b*b)),SQRT(sum(b*c)),SQRT(sum(b*d))....SQRT(sum(f*f))
```

- How could I use `threads` (in this
  case I guess 6 threads) to solve this
  and insert in a new table?
- And if I do not know the number of
  columns in the table, is there a way
  to create threads depending on the
  number of columns, of course knowing a threshold (for example not more than 10 threads)??

Currently I have something like:

```
SELECT SQRT(sum(a*a)),SQRT(sum(a*b)), .... ,SQRT(sum(f*f)) INTO TEMP FROM a_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your schema does not match to the type of information you wish to extract which why getting the information you want is such a pain. In this case, the values are not normalized. If you normalize them, the query becomes trivial:

```
With Inputs As
    (
    Select 1 As RowNum, 1.2 As a, 2.3 As b, 4.4 As c, 5.1 As d, 6.7 As e, 11.9 As f
    Union All Select 2, 7.2, 2.3, 4.3, 5.1, 4.7, 3.9   
    Union All Select 3, 1.9, 5.3, 3.3, 5.1, 3.7, 8.9   
    Union All Select 4, 5.2, 2.7, 7.4, 9.1, 1.7, 2.9 
    )
    , NormalizedInputs As
    (
    Select RowNum, 'a' As ColName, a As Value From Inputs
    Union All Select RowNum, 'b', b From Inputs
    Union All Select RowNum, 'c', c From Inputs
    Union All Select RowNum, 'd', d From Inputs
    Union All Select RowNum, 'e', e From Inputs
    Union All Select RowNum, 'f', f From Inputs
    )
Select N1.RowNum, Sqrt( Sum( N1.Value * N2.Value ) )
From NormalizedInputs As N1
    Left Join NormalizedInputs As N2
        On N2.RowNum = N1.RowNum
            And N2.ColName >= N1.ColName
Group By N1.RowNum
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit control of threading in SQL Server (or any other RDBMS that I'm aware of), *nor should there be*. While giving index hints and collation specifications within a query is one thing, people much smarter than you or I write query optimization engines and know how many threads to use (or not use) for any given operation.

So, the short answer is **you can't**.

If you have a need to do serious number-crunching and need that level of control, you'll have to pull the data into your application and do the processing there, where you have much greater control.

Comment: So how could you optimize that query?

Comment: @darkcminor: That query is pretty well optimized, and if it's required that you select your results as *columns*, then there isn't a whole lot that you can do to make it simpler. Are you having problems with it? If so, you should probably post a question with your specific issues. That'll get a much better response than asking how to work with threads.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but it's still what came up when I was searching for something similar. It also turned up this slightly less very old link:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4939/how-to-force-a-parallel-execution-plan-in-sql-server-2016/

Which suggested adding this to the end of the query:

OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 8649)

With it, my test query went from maxing out a single core in:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 23172 ms,  elapsed time = 23265 ms.
```

To about 8 cores almost full most of the time in:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 26492 ms,  elapsed time = 5612 ms.
```

So more total CPU time, but way less elapsed time.