# Vertical select results instead horizontal results SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Lets say I have a table like:

```
a     b    c     d    e      f
---------------------------------
1.2  2.3  4.4   5.1  6.7    11.9   
7.2  2.3  4.3   5.1  4.7    3.9   
1.9  5.3  3.3   5.1  3.7    8.9   
5.2  2.7  7.4   9.1  1.7    2.9
```

If I have to compute something as the sqrt of the multiplication of the sum of the columns

```
SQRT(sum(a*a)), SQRT(sum(a*b)), SQRT(sum(a*c)), SQRT(sum(a*d)), SQRT(sum(a*e)), 
SQRT(sum(a*f)), SQRT(sum(b*b)), SQRT(sum(b*c)), SQRT(sum(b*d)).... SQRT(sum(f*f))
```

Results:

```
id  result  operation
-----------------------------
1    x       a*a
2    y       a*b
...  ...     ...
n    z       f*f
```

instead of:

```
a*a     a*b   ...     f*f 
----------------------------
 x       y    ...      z
```

currently the query is

```
SELECT SQRT(sum(a*a)) AS a*a, SQRT(sum(a*b)) AS a*b, ...  , SQRT(sum(f*f)) AS f*f 
FROM Sometable
```

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111412/multi-threading-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
a FLOAT,
b FLOAT,
c FLOAT,
d FLOAT,
e FLOAT, 
f FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @T
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
(1, 1.2,2.3,4.4,5.1,6.7,11.9),
(2, 7.2,2.3,4.3,5.1,4.7,3.9), 
(3, 1.9,5.3,3.3,5.1,3.7,8.9), 
(4, 5.2,2.7,7.4,9.1,1.7,2.9) )  T(id,a,b,c,d,e, f)

;WITH U AS
(
SELECT * 
FROM @T
UNPIVOT (o FOR col IN (a,b,c,d,e, f)) unpvt
)
SELECT u1.col + '*' + u2.col as operation, SQRT(sum(u1.o*u2.o)) AS result
FROM U u1 JOIN U u2 ON u1.id=u2.id  AND u1.col <= u2.col
GROUP BY u2.col, u1.col
ORDER BY u2.col, u1.col
```

Comment: could you please explain a little the lines: FROM @T
UNPIVOT (o FOR col IN (a,b,c,d,e, f)) unpvt
) what exactly do they do?

Comment: @darkcminor - It converts the column structure into rows (basically the same as `NormalizedInputs` does in the other answer except with one pass through the data instead of 6). If you just run `SELECT * FROM @T UNPIVOT (o FOR col IN (a,b,c,d,e, f)) unpvt` it should be clear what's going on. From your comments on Thomas's answer putting your base data into this form might be easiest rather than trying to work with dynamic columns.

Comment: Ok, I guess your solution fits more to my problem.But have an extra question for you... is it possible to detect the cases x*y and y*x (for example a*b and b*a) as they are the same, so I avoid computing them again??

Comment: My answer should already do that, that is what the line `AND u1.col <= u2.col` is for. With that line you get 21 rows (6+5+4+3+2+1) without that you get 36)

Comment: @darkcminor - It should also be noted that like my solution, this is not dynamic. It's simply a different form of the same solution using the fancy Unpivot predicate. If you have 60 columns, your In clause will need to reference all 60 columns.

Comment: @Martin: How do you insert to a table the results of your query??

Comment: `SELECT.. result INTO #TABLE FROM U u1 ...` OR `INSERT INTO table SELECT...`

Answer (score 1):

```
With Inputs As
    (
    Select 1 As RowNum, 1.2 As a, 2.3 As b, 4.4 As c, 5.1 As d, 6.7 As e, 11.9 As f
    Union All Select 2, 7.2, 2.3, 4.3, 5.1, 4.7, 3.9   
    Union All Select 3, 1.9, 5.3, 3.3, 5.1, 3.7, 8.9   
    Union All Select 4, 5.2, 2.7, 7.4, 9.1, 1.7, 2.9 
    )
    , NormalizedInputs As
    (
    Select RowNum, 'a' As ColName, a As Value From Inputs
    Union All Select RowNum, 'b', b From Inputs
    Union All Select RowNum, 'c', c From Inputs
    Union All Select RowNum, 'd', d From Inputs
    Union All Select RowNum, 'e', e From Inputs
    Union All Select RowNum, 'f', f From Inputs
    )
Select N1.RowNum, Sqrt( Sum( N1.Value * N2.Value ) )
From NormalizedInputs As N1
    Left Join NormalizedInputs As N2
        On N2.RowNum = N1.RowNum
            And N2.ColName >= N1.ColName
Group By N1.RowNum
```

Comment: Ok, but what would you do if there are a lot more columns?, Is there a more general way to do this?

Comment: The problem I have is that there could be more than 60 columns... The solution you provide is right, but to make it general??

Comment: @darkcminor - SQL is not designed for, and therefore has no mechanism for, dynamic column generation. The only way to solve that problem is either to write out the columns statically, or use dynamic SQL. If you are going to use dynamic SQL, you shouldn't do it in T-SQL. You should do that in a middle-tier component.

Comment: @darkcminor - Btw, the `Inputs` CTE is obviously only for testing purposes. You would remove it and replace references to `Inputs` with the real source table.

Comment: @darkcminor / @Thomas - You say this solution is right but it only returns 4 rows. Have I misunderstood the requirement? I thought you needed `Group By N1.ColName, N2.ColName`

Comment: @Martin - It isn't clear whether the OP wants to calculate the values across each row, across the entire matrix or wants the individual calculations (which is where you would need the group by you mentioned). I assumed he was trying to evaluate the calculations per row.

Comment: @Martin - Btw, I based my assumption on the nature of the query he had so far. That query will return one calculation per row.